# How to calculate the MOSFET switching time?

Tags: mosfet, switching

I am generating high voltage negative pulses using N-MOS.
Switching rate is 150 ns (6.67 MHz). Can I use IRF830 for 6.67 MHz switching?
How can I calculate the switching time of N-MOS?
[image]

[image]
i am getting the high frequency oscillation during turn on. and i checked slowing down the rise time by adding series resistor at the gate, still the oscillation exists.
and added the Snubber at the switching node snab res=1ohm and Snab cap=600n. oscillation attenuates but the Vds is not dropping down to zero.

[image]

[image]

[image: Pulse not connected with mosfet]

Comment: Barely: max. delay&rise/fall times add up to 145 ns, driven by a perfect square wave using a 15 Ohms gate resistor switching a resistive load at 200 volts. That is an obsolete device looking its age.

Comment: `calculate the switching time of [a transistor]` You don't (beyond, say, adding delay and transition times). For one operating point, you can try and measure it. You can look up the specifications over a range of operating conditions - be sure to understand the parameters.

Comment: How do i calculate, is there any formula to calculate, datasheet says 16ns rise time and turn on delay of 8.2ns.

Comment: Please hyperlink the data sheet *for the exact device in question* in your question post.

Comment: Vishay gives those figures: https://www.vishay.com/docs/91063/91063.pdf Speeds will be faster for smaller driver source resistance (Rg), but only to a point. IRF830 is a very old part, it won't be suitable for very much power at this frequency.

Comment: What operating conditions are you looking to run at (voltage, current, power, type/class of power stage, etc.)?

Comment: @greybeard, where do you get 60ns from?

Comment: total cycle transition times = rise time + fall time. [ONSEMI IRF830](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/irf830-d.pdf) (\$max.\ t_r = t_f = t_{d(on)}\ = 30\ ns,\ t_{d(off)} = 55\ ns\ @\ V_{DD}\ 200\ V,\ R_G\ 15\ Ohms\$) - note that max 30 doesn't contradict 16 typical even without figuring in any differences in test setup parameters.

Comment: https://www.vishay.com/docs/91063/91063.pdf

Comment: ([alldatasheet](https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/32798/TRSYS/IRF830.html) is one resource to check variance in specifications.)

Comment: @Tim Willams, Yes part number is now changed to STD10NM60N. But still that be satisfied to operate at that speed of 6.67MHz. How do we verify that the switching speed. VDS is 300V, Vgs is 10V. Our requirement is generating the short negative voltage pulse at the output.

Comment: `part number is now changed to STD10NM60N` Please update the question body. Please specify D1 and reconsider the choice of D2.

Comment: (Maybe fully specify the requirements for those `high voltage negative pulses`.)

Comment: @greybeard, please check i have added the circuit now

Comment: `have added the circuit now` and a 'scope snapshot. Ch. 1 is \$V_D\$, 2 is \$V_G\$? wish I knew where 0V is, esp. with \$V_D\$. 600n for \$C_{snub}\$ sounds extreme, try 1n, \$R_{snub}\$ 33 Ohms. (@TimWilliams: I wish I knew how to take part of a comment chain to chat.)

Comment: i added 1nf, it not helps to reduces the oscillation.

Comment: Show a photo of the circuit layout.

Comment: MY guess is 10:1 probe ground or some other ground loop is too long. With 8 nH /mm it creates ringing with stray C and Coss and Ciss Cfb. I see 100 MHz resonance . Or perhaps you have mutual coupling. Shorten all paths, try to control your impedances and show layout is a must and probes. Often have we have written how to use 10:1 probes to expect a flat response to 200 MHz using tip and ring, spring probes etc

Comment: @Tim Williams, added the layout, check

Comment: @tony Stewart, yes i am using 10:1 with 11pF, 300MHz, 300V probe (N2842A) from keysight

Comment: What is Q30? Where is all the copper?

Comment: Scope is good, but probe accuracy is uncertain at 100 MHz with high dI/dt, dV/dt

Answer (score -1):

Rds(on) =1.5 Ω @ Vgs = 10 V for [IRF830](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91063/91063.pdf).and 0.5Ω  for STD10NM60

Your **turn-on resonance** on scope is 1/5 div. at 50 ns/div so 10 ns is 100 MHz resonance at turn on. This decays in about 5 cycles so I estimate the Q at 5 for reactance is 7.5 Ω  at 100 MHz.

The IRF capacitance is typical as follows;
[image]

Since Coss * RdsON =T is a fixed **Figure of Merit**, you have to choose a FET with a lower T or reduce the area of Effective Series Inductance, ESL.

[image]

My estimates may be wrong but this is how I would resolve the problem.

Perhaps an IGBT would work much faster. **650 V 14 pF 2.5A , Vce=2.1V @ 4A**

https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/igbt/rgt8tm65d-e.pdf

You have a great start in your layout. Showing the controlled impedances of every trace requires adding to the schematic all parasitic RLC values that affect resonance and showing all geometry in 3D.

The Keysight tools are excellent @ 300 MHz if used correctly.  You may need to create a 20 dB pad to 50 Ohms and run coax to 50 ohm termination on DSO.  or avoid the parasitic of your probe ground or insert a socket to probe with Tip and Ring.

Can you probe a 6.67 MHz square wave from a FET switch alone with 5V pullup and calibrate your probe with a textbook waveform with no 10th harmonic at 100 MHz? Compare how many cycles of ringing and frequency if possible and report in question.

I am unable to estimate ESL, ESR and (3D) pF parastics without more details.
[image]

I can however simulate your resonance with added RLC components in simulation (not shown). Your schematic needs more details to correct mine.

[image]

Comment: @stewart,  With IRF830S i am getting FOM=240psec and with STD8NM60N FOM=20psec,Lower FOM is good and Tradeoff between Rds(on) and Cgs again the STD8NM60N should be good(less in Conduction loss and Gate loss, compared to IRF830S mosfet.

Comment: 2nd order simulation will reveal more with the Millier effect and Cdg !   (Please reconsider my suggestions  to add to your question)

Comment: @Stewart, square wave from switch alone probed and attached, found there is no ringing

Comment: (I seem to remember [*Miller* effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_effect).)